# Alternativa a cache-control

Tags: html5, cache

Estoy buscando una alternativa a:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=1">
```

Para HTML5. El validador de W3C devuelve:

> "Error: Bad value cache-control for attribute http-equiv on element meta."

Y las alternativas no están muy claras.

Comment: Bienvenido. A la pregunta le falta agregar lo buscado/investigado sobre el tema así como también una descripción de lo que quieres lograr. Favor de seguir el [tour] y leer [ask].